# How to FTP a variable length file from linux to mainframe z/OS

Tags: ftp, mainframe, variable-length

I could not FTP a variable length file to mainframe; the operation was success, but the dataset generated on mainframe is not correct; can anyone help me.

procedures.

1. I have created a variable length dataset on mainframe.

   ```
   DSN=.TEST.DATA1
   LRECL=16
   ```

   Its content have 5 records, each has 12 characters:

   `000001 11AAAA000001
   000002 11AAAA000002
   000003 11AAAA000003
   000004 11AAAA000004
   000005 11AAAA000005`
2. download the dataset to linux using FTP client on a linux platform

   `ftp -v -n<
   user  
   prompt
   binary
   quote site rdw
   get TEST.DATA1
   close
   bye
   EOF`
3. the file was downloaded successfully.
4. upload the file back to mainframe

   `ftp -v -n<
   user  
   prompt
   binary
   quote site rdw recfm=v lrecl=16
   put TEST.DATA1 TEST.DATA2
   close
   bye
   EOF`
5. the new generated dataset TEST.DATA2 on mainframe is not correct.

   ```
    000001     11AAAA00
    000002 0001    11AA
    000003 AA000002

    000004 11AAAA000003
    000005     11AAAA00
    000006 0004    11AA
    000007 AA000005
   ```

   It seems the RDW field was treated as data field, this is not I expected; I wish the TEST.DATA2 has same as TEST.DATA1.

Thanks.

Comment: Try issuing the "LOCSITE RDW" command to the mainframe, I believe the default on may sites is "NORDW" which causes the mainframe to receive the record length as data. You might find the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21977135/192510) usefull

Comment: This command i was executed on a linux platform, it report keyword LOCSITE is not recognized.  <br/>
"500 unknown command locsite"