# What is the meaning of the first byte of each record set when downloading a v(b)-file from z/OS over FTP using "TYPE E" and "MODE B"

Tags: mainframe, zos, variable-length, dataformat

Right now, I'm trying to upload and download files with variable record lengths from an IBM mainframe running zOS 2.1. Like this guy: [How to FTP a variable length file from linux to mainframe z/OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377435/)

```
curl --user "******" --verbose --silent --show-error "ftp://themainframe/'SOME.FILE.NAME'" | hexdump

0000000 dead cafe babe
0000006


curl --user "******" --quote "site RDw" --verbose --silent --show-error "ftp://themainframe/'SOME.FILE.NAME'" | hexdump
0000000 000a 0000 dead cafe babe
000000a
```

It looks good. The rdw is "000a 0000" and the record "dead cafe babe". But. If I upload it again - even while using "quote site RDw" the server will ignore the RDW and store it as part of the actual data.

```
curl --user "******" --quote "site RDw" --verbose --silent --show-error "ftp://themainframe/'SOME.FILE.NAME'" > SOME.FILE.NAME
cat SOME.FILE.NAME | curl --user "******" --upload-file "-" --quote "site RDw" --verbose --silent --show-error "ftp://themainframe/'SOME.FILE.NAME'"
0000000 000c 0000 0008 0000 dead beef
000000c
```

Since that's not what I wanted, I searched some more. And - I found this article:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21188301

And gave it another try.

```
curl --user "******" --quote "TYPE E" --quote "MODE B" --verbose --silent --show-error "ftp://themainframe/'SOME.FILE.NAME'" | hexdump
0000000 4000 04de adbe ef00
0000007
```

That looked interesting. So I compared it with another file, containing a larger dataset...

```
0000000 4002 cbdc...
00002ce
```

And another one...

```
0000000 8000 16f0...
0000019 4000 16f0...
0000032
```

My first impression is: An 80 seems to indicate that there will be more datasets, whereas the 40 indicates the last one. That seemed to be true for every file I tried. For a normal file with variable record lengths as well as for a blocked file withe variable record lengths.

So I tried to upload it again...

```
curl --user "******" --quote "TYPE E" --quote "MODE B" --verbose --silent --show-error "ftp://themainframe/'SOME.FILE.NAME'" > SOME.FILE.NAME
cat SOME.FILE.NAME | curl --user "******" --upload-file "-" --quote "TYPE E" --quote "MODE B" --verbose --silent --show-error "ftp://themainframe/'SOME.FILE.NAME'"
```

And it seemed to work

Well - at least now I'm able to transfer files with variable record lengths from and to the mainframe while preserving the record lengths.

**But - and here is the question:**
Is the first byte of each record "only" an indicator for wheather there will be more data sets? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to use `--quote "locsite rdw"` if you're uploading. [locsite](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.halu001/locsite.htm) is the inverse of `site`.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work:

`> locsite rdw
< 500 unknown command locsite`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. locsite is only valid for a z/OS to z/OS transfer. Unix/Windows etc have no concept of record oriented files so it's not possible to do what you want. There's a good thread about it [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bit.listserv.ibm-main/QIAmIGxP0XA/2ssqVJtTIRcJ).

Comment: You know ... it works. as I have described in my original post. I just want to know what the first byte of each record means...

Comment: Check out the [Using data sets manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_1.13.0/com.ibm.zos.r13.idad400/d4356.htm) which documents format V records. I thought it might be the BDW but according to your dump it's not as a BDW is 4 bytes. What do you mean it works? Are you saying that you can successfully download and then upload a format V data set from z/OS to Linux and then back again? If so I'm dubious because it's well documented that that's not possible without using an intermediate file or writing code using RECFM=U transfers.

Comment: I tripped over this and thought I'd add my '1 bit worth'.
A record in z/OS can be up to 32760 bytes in length. So you need more than a byte to record the length, but less than a full 2 bytes - in particular, the high order bit is not required for the length. My hunch is that the first bit is being used as you suggest. To make sure everything is working as you expect, I'd try a file with a record that's the full 32760 wide to make sure it's all good. 
Another interesting test is that a record can be 0 bytes long too... That's valid.

Answer (score -1):

The first byte of a variable block record is the record length, so that's what you are seeing